# How to access all table in json object

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I have a json object that has multiple table and each table has multiple column, i want to access all table and then all column in each table, here is some sample data in my json object..

```js
{
  "Table1": [{
    "AColumn": "3123121288",
    "BColumn": "\/Date(1449064218000+0500)\/",
    "CColumn": "865342608608",
    "DColumn": "12422008054140",
    "EColumn": "Plot # 11-C, Bukhari Commercial Street-2, Phase-VI, DHA, Karachi.",
    "FColumn": "67.058",
    "GColumn": "67.058"
  }, {
    "AColumn": "3123121288",
    "BColumn": "\/Date(1449064218000+0500)\/",
    "CColumn": "865342608608",
    "DColumn": "12422008054140",
    "EColumn": "Plot # 11-C, Bukhari Commercial Street-2, Phase-VI, DHA, Karachi.",
    "FColumn": "67.058",
    "GColumn": "67.058"
  }],
  "Table2": [{
    "AColumn": "3123121288",
    "BColumn": "\/Date(1449064218000+0500)\/",
    "CColumn": "865342608608",
    "DColumn": "12422008054140",
    "EColumn": "Plot # 11-C, Bukhari Commercial Street-2, Phase-VI, DHA, Karachi.",
    "FColumn": "67.058",
    "GColumn": "67.058"
  }, {
    "AColumn": "3123121288",
    "BColumn": "\/Date(1449064218000+0500)\/",
    "CColumn": "865342608608",
    "DColumn": "12422008054140",
    "EColumn": "Plot # 11-C, Bukhari Commercial Street-2, Phase-VI, DHA, Karachi.",
    "FColumn": "67.058",
    "GColumn": "67.058"
  }],
  "Table3": {
    "AColumn": "3123121288",
    "BColumn": "\/Date(1449064218000+0500)\/",
    "CColumn": "865342608608",
    "DColumn": "12422008054140",
    "EColumn": "Plot # 11-C, Bukhari Commercial Street-2, Phase-VI, DHA, Karachi.",
    "FColumn": "67.058",
    "GColumn": "67.058"
  },
  {
    "AColumn": "3123121288",
    "BColumn": "\/Date(1449064218000+0500)\/",
    "CColumn": "865342608608",
    "DColumn": "12422008054140",
    "EColumn": "Plot # 11-C, Bukhari Commercial Street-2, Phase-VI, DHA, Karachi.",
    "FColumn": "67.058",
    "GColumn": "67.058"
  }],
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post some code to show what you tried. Also search SO for examples

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
  "Table1": [{
    "AColumn": "3123121288",
    "BColumn": "\/Date(1449064218000+0500)\/",
    "CColumn": "865342608608",
    "DColumn": "12422008054140",
    "EColumn": "Plot # 11-C, Bukhari Commercial Street-2, Phase-VI, DHA, Karachi.",
    "FColumn": "67.058",
    "GColumn": "67.058"
  }, {
    "AColumn": "3123121288",
    "BColumn": "\/Date(1449064218000+0500)\/",
    "CColumn": "865342608608",
    "DColumn": "12422008054140",
    "EColumn": "Plot # 11-C, Bukhari Commercial Street-2, Phase-VI, DHA, Karachi.",
    "FColumn": "67.058",
    "GColumn": "67.058"
  }],
  "Table2": [{
    "AColumn": "3123121288",
    "BColumn": "\/Date(1449064218000+0500)\/",
    "CColumn": "865342608608",
    "DColumn": "12422008054140",
    "EColumn": "Plot # 11-C, Bukhari Commercial Street-2, Phase-VI, DHA, Karachi.",
    "FColumn": "67.058",
    "GColumn": "67.058"
  }, {
    "AColumn": "3123121288",
    "BColumn": "\/Date(1449064218000+0500)\/",
    "CColumn": "865342608608",
    "DColumn": "12422008054140",
    "EColumn": "Plot # 11-C, Bukhari Commercial Street-2, Phase-VI, DHA, Karachi.",
    "FColumn": "67.058",
    "GColumn": "67.058"
  }],
  "Table3": [{
    "AColumn": "3123121288",
    "BColumn": "\/Date(1449064218000+0500)\/",
    "CColumn": "865342608608",
    "DColumn": "12422008054140",
    "EColumn": "Plot # 11-C, Bukhari Commercial Street-2, Phase-VI, DHA, Karachi.",
    "FColumn": "67.058",
    "GColumn": "67.058"
  },
  {
    "AColumn": "3123121288",
    "BColumn": "\/Date(1449064218000+0500)\/",
    "CColumn": "865342608608",
    "DColumn": "12422008054140",
    "EColumn": "Plot # 11-C, Bukhari Commercial Street-2, Phase-VI, DHA, Karachi.",
    "FColumn": "67.058",
    "GColumn": "67.058"
  }]
}
for (var table in obj) {
  document.write('<table><thead>')  
  
  for (var columns in obj[table][0]) {
    document.write('<th>'+columns+'</th>')
  }
  document.write('</thead>')  
  for (var i=0;i<obj[table].length;i++) {
    var row = obj[table][i];
    document.write('<tr>');
    for (var columns in row) {
      document.write('<td>'+row[columns]+'</td>')
    }
    document.write('</tr>');
  }
  document.write('</table>')  
}
```

```css
table, td { border:1px solid black}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result =[];
var jsonObj = yourJsonObject;

for (var key in jsonObj){result.push(jsonObj[key])}

console.log(result);
```